# JQuery - Cannot seem to bind event to dynamic DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

Using JQuery UI Draggable, I am cloning elements as they leave an unordered list. As these are new to the DOM, i'm trying to use the JQuery On() method to bind an event which will show a hidden link. The anchor with the class cancel has `display: none;` in the css.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="current-campaign">
    <li class="draggable">One <a class="pull-right cancel" href="#">
          <i style="color:red">Icon</i>
        </a>

    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="new-campaign sortable"></ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".sortable").sortable();
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone",
});

$(".current-campaign").on("mouseout", ".cancel", function () {
    $(".cancel").show();
});
```

Really having trouble figuring out why the link doesn't show up when it leaves the unordered list. Here's a JS fiddle to see it in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/og937wy7/

**FINAL EDIT WITH ANSWER**
Armed with the knowledge of how to use the on() function, I fixed up my code so it's working as I intended.

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".new-campaign", function (e) {
    console.error($(this));
    $(".new-campaign").find('.cancel').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/og937wy7/4/

Comment: Hi, have a look at my answer. If it works out for you, click on the `✔` button next to my answer to accept it as a way of telling thanks to me. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attaching an event to `.cancel`, which is not at all in the view:

```
$(".current-campaign").on("mouseout", ".cancel", function () {
    $(".cancel").show();
});
```

How can you `mouseout`, when `.cancel` doesn't have an area? Replace it with `.draggable`:

```
$(".current-campaign").on("mouseout", ".draggable", function () {
    $(".cancel").show();
});
```

I guess you are looking for the cancel to be shown once you hover and when you come away, it should hide. So change your code to:

```
$(".current-campaign, .new-campaign").on("mouseout", ".draggable", function () {
    $(".cancel").hide();
}).on("mouseover", ".draggable", function () {
    $(".cancel").show();
});
```

I would also tell this is not a right way, because, it affects all the `.cancel`. So you might need to use `$(this).find()`:

```
$(".current-campaign, .new-campaign").on("mouseout", ".draggable", function () {
    $(this).find(".cancel").hide();
}).on("mouseover", ".draggable", function () {
    $(this).find(".cancel").show();
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpojx7so/**

**But, everything can be done using CSS itself!!!**

You just need to add this CSS, instead of the whole JS:

```
.sortable:hover .cancel {
    display: inline;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mx58stx3/**

Comment: thanks for the good post! You helped me understand how i was using the on() function incorrectly. You misunderstood my goal though, so the latter half of your post isn't applicable. I've updated my question with my final code, however. Thanks again!